# how to set EOF to istream in order to stop reading?

Tags: c++, stream, std, istream

I would like to stop reading from `istream` (`std::cin` specifically) by setting EOF bit (in which case I guess the `istream` should stop reading anything else). This is the scenario:

*date.hpp*:

```
class Date
{
    std::stringstream format;
    time_t date;
    struct tm date_tm;

public:
    Date()
    {
        date = time(NULL);
        struct tm *tmp = localtime(&date);
        date_tm = *tmp;
    }
    Date(std::istream &in);
    Date(std::string s);
    Date(const Date &);
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &, Date &);

    std::string getAll() const;
    int getDay() const;
    int getMonth() const;
    int getYear() const;
};
```

*date.cpp*:

```
bool isDate(std::string target)
{
    std::regex reg("(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/([0-2][1-9]|3[0-1])/([0-9]{2})");
    return std::regex_search(target, reg);
}

std::string readDate(std::istream &in)
{
    std::cout << "enter date [mm/dd/yy]: ";
    std::string input;
    std::getline(in, input);
    //HERE
    //before checking the right format in "isDate"
    // I want to check for "exit" string to set EOF to "in"
    if(input == "exit")
    {
        //now set EOF
        //...
    }

    if (isDate(input))
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Ill formated date");
    }
}
```

You can see from above, that I want to set EOF to istream before any more parsing, and exit. Otherwise I cannot stop the istream from reading, since anything else will throw `std::invalid_argument` (So I cannot `C^D` for key to trigger EOF). The reason the istream is reading to infinity is because of this:

```
int main()
{
    vector<Date> e;
    copy(istream_iterator<Date>(cin), istream_iterator<Date>(), back_inserter(e));
    //when will you end?
}
```

for `std::copy`, the default `istream_iterator()` is `end-of-stream`, which I want to trigger by that `EOF`. so how to set EOF?

Comment: This sounds stupid and counterintuitive, but you can [use `clear`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) to set stream state. [`setstate` probably makes more sense, though](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/setstate).

Comment: Note that if you have to perform little hacks like this, using a canned algorithm might not be the best solution. Future readers of your code need to understand the little hack, why it's being performed, and why they shouldn't mess with it. The odds of errors being injected during maintenance go way up.